# js substr() не обрезает текст

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Пытаюсь сделать обрезку текста по количеству символов:

```
$(".text-article").text(function(i, text) {
   if (text.lenght >= 10) {
       text = text.substr(0, 10);
       let lastIndex = text.lastIndexOf(" ");   
       text = text.substr(0, lastIndex) + '...';
   }
   $(this).text(text);
});
```

И ничего не происходит, но если прямо в консоле обрезать текст, то все нормально. Не могу понять в чем проблема. html код создает php скрипт, может в этом проблема?

Comment: а может не lenght а length

Comment: @Избытоксусликов мда уж, спасибо! Браузер почему-то не показывал ошибок вот я не понял.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(".text-article").text(function(i, text) {
   if (text.length >= 10) {
       text = text.substr(0, 10);
       let lastIndex = text.lastIndexOf(" ");   
       text = text.substr(0, lastIndex) + '...';
   }
   $(this).text(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-article">Hi guys How are u doing :) ?</div>
```